# Drop down component for string in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

what is the best way to render drop down for String values in Hybris for my storefront?Should I render it just like HTML and Javascript and take the content from some AJAX calls?I wanted some content like:Monday,Tuesday,... as a drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular approach with Spring MVC and forms. There are lots of articles and tutorials for it. e.g. here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/